# What is the term for when a person gets out of doing a task by saying "you are better at that than I am so you can do it"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the term for when a person gets out of doing a task by saying to someone:

> You are better at that than I am so you can do it.

I read an article a few years ago about this term but I cannot remember it.

Comment: "At that than I am"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word or phrase for doing something poorly so that someone else does it for you?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232049/word-or-phrase-for-doing-something-poorly-so-that-someone-else-does-it-for-you)

Comment: Funny how nobody ever shows up here asking for our help in saying something ***nice*** about somebody else. Instead it's always about saying horrible things about something we disapprove of, even though this has never required fancy words to sting the worst.

Answer (score 1):

[It is called strategic incompetence.](https://www.theskimm.com/wellness/weaponized-incompetence)  Among other people who have mentioned this are Scott Adams, the originator of the Dilbert comic strip. It is a recurring theme in the strip with *many* variations. One of the primary characters with this as a feature of his personality is Wally.

[image]

Comment: I wonder why you didn’t go with the main name in your linked article that they use at least five or six times instead of the offhand “also called” reference they mention once.